# How does a server know a request is sent with credentials?

Tags: http, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I've been having a problem that just cropped up when requesting a resource from another server through my website.

I request the resource (a PDF file requested through Range Requests). 
The browser (Chrome in this case) sends an OPTIONS request to the server.
The server returns 200 from the OPTIONS, but one of the headers is - `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
Since the server exposes the wildcard `*` for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, Chrome then (I think) throws out the following responses from the server and gives me an error saying that the server can't expose the wildcard if the request is made `withCredentials = 'include'`.

Now, I'm not setting the `withCredentials` flag anywhere in my code that I can see and **I can't seem to find out how the server knows if a request is sent withCredentials**.  My cookies aren't sent with the OPTIONS or following GET/PARTIAL CONTENT requests.  There's no other special headers in the request that I can see.

So,

1. How does the server know and how can I tell on the client side wither credentials are set to include?
2. If I'm not setting credentials on my side, what could be causing Chrome to think that the mode I'm using is `withCredentials = 'include'`?
3. Should the server be sending back the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header on ALL requests after the OPTIONS?

Comment: @sideshowbarker In answer to your last point, I both can't and it doesn't matter.  I'm setting withCredentials to false explicitly, but the request does route through some vendor code before actually sending out.  And that code is minified JS and/or WASM C code.  I'd accept the comments as a valid answer as it reinforces what I expected to hear.  My guess is the vendor code is setting it somehow, I just can't find it and will be contacting them.  If I can't check programmatically for 'withCredentials' then I'm not sure what else I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How does the server know and how can I tell on the client side wither credentials are set to include?

The receiving server doesn’t know anything about the client-side `withCredentials` setting. The server just receives some form of credentials in the request, or doesn’t. And as far as the CORS protocol goes, the receiving server doesn’t change its behavior based on whether the request includes credentials or not. The receiving server either just sends back the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header, or doesn’t.

> 2. If I'm not setting credentials on my side, what could be causing Chrome to think that the mode I'm using is `withCredentials = 'include'`?

The answer to that is, it’s subjective — it depends on who the server admin intends the response for. But best practice is, you probably only want to send back `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to particular origins that you know and explicitly want to allow. That’s why the CORS protocol has the restriction that it won’t allow your frontend code to access a response if the request has credentials and the response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (wildcard) header value.

> 3. Should the server be sending back the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header on ALL requests after the OPTIONS?

Chrome would only think that if the mode actually really *is* `withCredentials = 'include'`. So either some part of your client code *is* actually setting `withCredentials = 'include'` — or else, `withCredentials = 'include'` *isn’t* actually getting set all but you for some reason just think it is.

Comment: *as far as the CORS protocol goes, the receiving server doesn’t change its behavior based on whether the request includes credentials or not.* Unfortunately, the Fetch standard isn't very prescriptive: *Ultimately server developers have a lot of freedom in how they handle HTTP responses [...]* I've seen questionable and wonky CORS configs where the server changes it CORS responses if it detects cookies in the request; of course, that only sort of works for _simple_ credentialed requests.